# How to create Asp.Net MVC 3 view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have a database through which I connect to by using Entity framework. My Home View consists of many partial views that display different parts of the application. In my controller i would like to send a model containing all those different Entity data objects to my view, and then send the needed info to my particular partial views. I believe I need a view model for this but have never done this before. Let me summarize my objective:
I have four tables: currentFav,TopTenFav,Genres, and Songs
I have created a repository class with some query functions such as find all the songs, add a song and so on.
My index view is divided into partial views such as current fav, top ten, and genres.

My question is how would I send my model from the controller to my view and then from there to all of my partial views, anyone got an idea? thx

Answer (score 0):

How I would design your ViewModel is to create an Interface for each of your Partial views such that:

```
interface IPartialView1  //Name it appropriately
{
   currentFav CurrentFav { get; }
}
```

Then on your actual ViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel : IPartialView1, IPartialView2,....
{
   currentFav CurrentFav { get; set; }
}
```

Populate your HomeViewModel as you see fit, and in your partial views:

```
<!-- CurrentFav-Partial.cshtml -->
@Model IPartialView1

<span>@model.CurrentFav.color</span>
```

This allows you to create any Model you want to pass into the view, and as long as it has the interface each of the Partials need to render they can.  Each ViewModel can contain any number of other models/classes via Interfaces for any type of view you create.

Comment: one question, where would i create the interfaces? in my model folder or my views folder?

Comment: For simplicity I would recommend in the Model folder.  The only thing in the views folder should be html-ish files.

Comment: so what i understand i would have four interfaces, or one interface with: currentFav CurrentFav { get; } topTenFave TopTenFave...

Comment: If you need to discuss this I would recommend chatting http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/4649/how-to-create-asp-net-mvc-3-view-model?tab=general.

Comment: _PartialTopTenFav.cshtml this is one of my views so how would i implement an interface to this? i'm a little confused