# What is the best way to handle creating, and updating Complex Datatypes in MVC3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Ok I've been trying to figure out the best way to do this for a few days, but still haven't come up with a very elegant answer so am hoping I someone can point me in the right direction or give some peer review :)

Basically I have 3 classes (they are different and much more complex than these):

```
public class Person
{
    int ID { get; set;}
    string Name { get; set; }
    virtual IEnumerable<Place> { get; set; }

}

public class Place
{
    int ID { get; set;}
    string Name { get; set; }
    virtual IEnumerable<Thing> { get; set; }
}

public class Thing
{
    int ID { get; set;}
    string Name { get; set; }
    virtual IEnumerable<Place> { get; set; }
    virtual int PersonID { get; set; }
}
```

So basically you have `Person`s, who have many `Place`s, which can have many `Thing`s which can also appear in multiple `Places` (trying to reduce having to store duplicates of `Thing`s) but only for that `Person`

What is the best way to setup my ViewModel to handle this? Should I just create everything by itself using Ajax and Json (what I've been doing) or is there a way to handle this type of relationship in a ViewModel and single post back to the server?

Currently I'm doing the following:

Fill out `Person` form -> ajax save to server, get `Person ID`

Fill out `Place` form (including `Person`'s `ID`) -> ajax save to server, get `Place ID`

Fill out `Thing` form (including `Person ID` and `Place ID`s in a delimited string

I know there should be an easier way to do this as its kinda bulky, but since its all query string I can't figure it out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You say "kinda bulky," but I think it tends to be more lightweight if you can build an object graph on a form in real time by using AJAX/JSON, probably against a RESTful API, somewhat as you describe.

The alternative is using script (jQuery, JSMVC, Knockout) to build a form and POST the whole sucker at once. I've had to do this in some situations where none of the data should be persisted until the whole graph is committed. The trick here is understanding ModelBinder and how it builds/updates that graph for you.

If this is what you were asking, I can expand on the key points of how ModelBinder deals with complex object graphs and collections.

Comment: Ok, I'll keep going with what I have been working on then, I just wanted to check if there was an easier way that I was overlooking. Thanks for mentioning Knockout, hadn't heard of it before, will have to try it for another project :)

Comment: Yea Knockout is wicked for binding a whole graph to the UI. Good luck! So, did I answer your question? ;)

Comment: If no-one else weighs in with a better way looks like it :). I was hoping I was missing something with some advanced viewmodel stuff, but I'm not sure how you'd send a list through post without having to manually parse it. I'm going to leave it open for a bit to see if someone else has any ideas or input. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

I answered a similar question about how to handle this using interfaces and partial views.

[How to create Asp.Net MVC 3 view model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7971953/how-to-create-asp-net-mvc-3-view-model/7972068#7972068)

Comment: My question is similar, but I'm wondering what the best way to save the information is, not how to display it. I'm trying to find out how I can post all of that information correctly so I can then save it to the database.